# How can I correctly make a for loop for my variables?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a code here that gets 6 NON repeating numbers between 0 and 45, so far its working, except I want a loop to change my numbers so that if the number is lower than 10, it adds a 0 in front, so that every number has the format "xx" for example "07", "25" , "00"

Im trying to make a for loop for my code, but it breaks every time I try it. Im trying to reduce the lenght of my code with this for loop.

My code is now working, but I have a nasty 6 if's statements.

Ive allready tried this:

```
    var z;
    for (z = 1; z < 7; z++) { 
      if (n[z] < 10) {
        n[z] = "0" + n[z];
      }
    }
```

This is my code:

```js
function randomNo(){



function arrayShuffle () {
       var i = this.length, j, temp;
       if ( i === 0 ) return false;
       while ( --i ) {
          j = Math.floor( Math.random() * ( i + 1 ) );
          temp = this[i];
          this[i] = this[j];
          this[j] = temp;
       }
    }

Array.prototype.shuffle =arrayShuffle;

var start = 0;
var end = 45;
var numbers = new Array();
for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    numbers.push(i);
}
numbers.shuffle();

var n1 = numbers.pop();
var n2 = numbers.pop();
var n3 = numbers.pop();
var n4 = numbers.pop();
var n5 = numbers.pop();
var n6 = numbers.pop();

// Should replace for a for loop, but I cant figure it out

    

// Replace in html


            console.log(n1);
            console.log(n2);
            console.log(n3);
            console.log(n4);
            console.log(n5);
            console.log(n6);

}

randomNo();
```

Every time I tried the for loop, my numbers stop working at all, and in the HTML I only get my starting text which awaits the replacement by the Query Selector.

Comment: Create a fiddle here with the <> button to replicate the issue and tell us what the console in your browser tells you is the error in your code

Comment: you melting string and number. use parseInt; and debug your code ( F12)

Comment: please, try to add a more meaningful title to your questions

Comment: @LelioFaieta Done, thanks,

Comment: @MrJ `parseInt` will round the value to a single digit, so `02` will be rounded to just `2` and thats not what he wants, although I'm not actually sure of what he wants.

Comment: @mrJ - I want what my code actually does, but without those 6 if statements that I added, because I believe that is just bad practice and I am trying to learn. Im making a non repeating random number generator which spits 6 numbers between 0 and 45, except I want every number under 10 to be in the format "xx" so 2 will be 02, and 7 will be 07, and 0 will be 00.

Comment: `var number = i < 10 ? "0"+i :  i;` is a bad response, if th number is <10 it return a string, otherwise it return a interger = > this is a mix. Better to do `var numberStr = i < 10 ? "0"+i : i.toString();` like Robert suggest

Comment: @MrJ thank you for pointing that out, I will correct that so that all muy outputs are strings.

Comment: so, did you notice my answer about a loop to create your variables ?

Comment: @MrJ Yes I did, but It does not work for me, since I need non repeating values.

Comment: by non-repetitive values, do you mean that all values must be different? __ so I changed my code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the idea is just to get 6 random 'int.toString' 2 digits values into 6 JS vars with the same prefix name and a number between 0 an 46, no need to create a wrapper or Array :

```js
var randomIntStr = {
  _list : [],
  GetNoRepeat(max) {
    let r = 0;
    do { r = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max)); }
    while (this._list.includes(r));
    this._list.push(r);
    return r < 10 ? "0" + r : r.toString();
  }
};



for (let i=1; i<7;i++) {
  window['n'+i] = randomIntStr.GetNoRepeat(46);
}

console.log('n1 =', n1);
console.log('n2 =', n2);
console.log('n3 =', n3);
console.log('n4 =', n4);
console.log('n5 =', n5);
console.log('n6 =', n6);
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert the number to a string, then:

1) Use `padStart` method of strings:

```js
function ex(inp) {
  return inp.toString().padStart(2, '0');
} 

console.log(ex(1));
console.log(ex(154));
console.log(ex(9));
```

2) Check the length of the string and if it's lower than 2, add a leading 0:

```js
function ex(numb) {
  return numb.toString().length < 2 ? `0${numb}` : numb;
}

console.log(ex(1));
console.log(ex(154));
console.log(ex(13));
console.log(ex(9));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this at fill time :

```
for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        numbers.push((i < 10 ? "0" : "") + i); // This will generate "08", "09", "10"
}
```

But if you just want an array of 6 random numbers between 0 and 45, you can generate an array of 6 empty (undefined) elements, that you loop over and fill with a random 0~45 number :

```js
let numbers = Array.from(Array(6)).map(() => {
  let n = Math.floor(Math.random()*46);
  return (n < 10 ? "0" : "") + n
})

console.log(numbers)
```

...that you can then loop over :

```
for(let num in numbers){
     document.querySelector(`.rn${num}`).innerText = num;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to add that the 6 random numbers cant repeat themselves

Comment: Ah, forget about my generator then :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using map()

```js
function arrayShuffle () {
           var i = this.length, j, temp;
           if ( i === 0 ) return false;
           while ( --i ) {
              j = Math.floor( Math.random() * ( i + 1 ) );
              temp = this[i];
              this[i] = this[j];
              this[j] = temp;
           }
        }

    Array.prototype.shuffle =arrayShuffle;

    var start = 0;
    var end = 45;
    var numbers = new Array();
    for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        numbers.push(i);
    }
    numbers.shuffle();
    
    numbers = numbers.map(function (n) {
        return n < 10 ? "0" + n : n.toString();
    });
    
    console.log(numbers);
```